# Compilation error: Undefined reference to

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-12.04, udev

I'm working on a C program for getting events from Udev.  The program has been compiled and tested on a host running Debian (With GCC 4.7.2-5).

Recently, switched to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (With GCC 4.6.3).  The same program fails to compile and halts during the linking phase.

```
automounter_main.c:(.text+0xd4e): undefined reference to `udev_new'
automounter_main.c:(.text+0xe02): undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_devnum'
automounter_main.c:(.text+0xeb0): undefined reference to `udev_device_new_from_syspath'
automounter_main.c:(.text+0xf63): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_list_entry'
automounter_main.c:(.text+0xf77): undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name'
automounter_main.c:(.text+0xf85): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
automounter_main.c:(.text+0x100a): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
automounter_main.c:(.text+0x1055): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_sysattr_value'
automounter_main.c:(.text+0x1078): undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_next'
automounter_main.c:(.text+0x108c): undefined reference to `udev_device_get_parent'
automounter_main.c:(.text+0x1118): undefined reference to `udev_device_unref'
automounter_main.c:(.text+0x1122): undefined reference to `udev_unref'
```

The following steps were taken, but nothing seems to work.

- Install all packages related to udev (udev, libudev-dev, libudev0).  All the packages are reported to be the latest.
- Create a Symlink in /usr/lib pointing the correct udev library.
- Upgraded libc package

Symlink was verified using:

```
$ ls -l libudev*

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    39 Nov 27 15:57 libudev.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0)
```

Kindly help me find a way to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously the linker fails to link some udev library. Check (or post here) your linker command and whether the right library is provided with `-l` and/or `-L`.

Comment: @usr1234567 Thanks for pointing the linker. I obviously didn't pay attention to the order of the parameters given there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that you need to move `-ludev` to the end of the linking command line.

Comment: You are right, the -ludev seems to have been given before the objects.  It has now been corrected.